# HQL- Select new constructor with boolean parameters

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I'm trying to call the testResultDTO constructor with a boolean parameter but keep geting an error

TestResultDTO :

```
public class TestResultDTO extends AbstractDTO {

    private Boolean test;
    private Boolean locked;


    public TestResultDTO() {

    super();
    }


    public TestResultDTO(Boolean locked, Boolean test) {

    super();
    this.test = test;
    this.locked = locked;
    }
```

the query:

```
SELECT NEW com.xxx.model.dto.widgets.results.TestResultDTO(p.isLocked, IF((p.playerStatus = 'STANDARD'), false, true)) From player p Where p.id = 1
```

the error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.ReflectHelper.getConstructor(ReflectHelper.java:355)
```

Is there a way to pass a boolean parameter hard coded ('true')??

Comment: well i think u need to use 0 or 1 for the same. try it once.

Comment: tried it and still getting the same error

Comment: why u using new then u can give field instead of that.

Comment: This is just an example of a larger constructor. I have several "If" conditions that are much more complicated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The query may be like this :-

```
SELECT NEW com.xxx.model.dto.widgets.results.TestResultDTO(p.isLocked, CASE WHEN p.playerStatus = 'STANDARD' then false  else true end) From player p Where p.id = 1 .
```

**For reference :** http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-expressions